# Twitter Javascript plugins "BootStrap"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I have just achieved the basic of hiding and showing found [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

**Here is a working sample code:**

```
<div id="content" class="collapse" >
//Place content in here
</div>
<a href="content" data-toggle="collapse" style="cursor:pointer;">Read More</a>
```

My next task is to create a change of "Read More" to "Read Less" on a click event.

The problem is how can I check what event is going on and how to use it.

**Sample Twitter Code**

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden', function () {
    // do something…
    })
```

Parts I don't understand is what is '#myCollapsible'? Would that be the div id that got shrinked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be correct to use

```
$('#content')
```

instead of using

```
$('#myCollapsible')
```

in your case :)

Answer (score 0):

A full solution would be:

```
$( '#content' ).on( 'hidden', function() {
    $( 'a[href="' + this.id + '"]' ).html( 'Read More' );
}).on( 'shown', function() {
    $( 'a[href="' + this.id + '"]' ).html( 'Read Less' );
});
```

If you want something generic you could replace `$( '#content' )` with `$( '.collapse' )`.

Comment: Could you add jsfiddle as a proof for it?